# Convert string which illustrates some list into pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have the following string:

```
s = '[[[1],1,¬q,"A",[]],[[2],2,p→q,"A",[]],[[3],3,p,"A",[]],[[2,3],4,q,"→E",[2,3]],[[1,2,3],5,q∧ ¬q,"∧I",[1,4]],[[1,2],6,¬p,"¬I",[3,5]]]'
```

My aim now is to convert this into some pandas dataframe with columns:

```
        df = pd.DataFrame(
                   columns=['Assumptions', 'Index', 'Proposition', 'Premisses', 'Rule'])
```

which can be illustrated in console as follows:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: You would need to parse the input string and map it to an object that can later be mapped to the dataframe row (e.g. dictionary with the keys as columns you mentioned).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a case for regular expressions.

```py
import re
from ast import literal_eval
import pandas as pd

s = ('[[[1],1,¬q,"A",[]],[[2],2,p→q,"A",[]],[[3],3,p,"A",[]],'
     '[[2,3],4,q,"→E",[2,3]],[[1,2,3],5,q∧ ¬q,"∧I",[1,4]],[[1,2],6,¬p,"¬I",[3,5]]]')

rows = []

# split at ',' followed by two closing ]]
for x in re.split(r"(?<=\]\]),", s[1:-1]):
    
    # split at ',' after closing ] OR between '"' and opening [ 
    left, middle, right = re.split(r"(?<=\]),(?=\d)|(?<=\"),(?=\[)", x[1:-1])

    # split the middle part at ','
    middle = middle.split(",")
    
    rows.append([literal_eval(left), *middle, literal_eval(right)])
    


df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['Assumptions', 'Index', 'Proposition', 'Premisses', 'Rule'])
df["Index"] = df.Index.astype(int)
df["Premisses"] = df.Premisses.str.strip('"')
```

Result:

```py
  Assumptions  Index Proposition Premisses    Rule
0         [1]      1          ¬q         A      []
1         [2]      2         p→q         A      []
2         [3]      3           p         A      []
3      [2, 3]      4           q        →E  [2, 3]
4   [1, 2, 3]      5       q∧ ¬q        ∧I  [1, 4]
5      [1, 2]      6          ¬p        ¬I  [3, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution does not require Regex

```
import pandas as pd

s = '[[[1],1,¬q,"A",[]],[[2],2,p→q,"A",[]],[[3],3,p,"A",[]],[[2,3],4,q,"→E",[2,3]],[[1,2,3],5,q∧ ¬q,"∧I",[1,4]],[[1,2],6,¬p,"¬I",[3,5]]]'
s1 = s[2:-2].split('],[')
result = []

for item in s1:
    lst = []
    group = False
    temp = ''

    for e in item:
        #extract group with square brackets `[ ]`
        if e == '[':
            group = True
            temp = ''
        elif e == ']' and temp[-1] != ']':
            temp += e
            lst.append(temp)
            group = False
            temp = ''

        if group == True:
            temp += e
        elif e != ']':
            #below non-group, to extract string between commas `,`
            if e == ',' and temp != '':
                lst.append(temp)
                temp = ''
            elif e != ',' and e != '"':
                temp += e

    result.append(lst)

df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['Assumptions', 'Index', 'Proposition', 'Premisses', 'Rule'])
print(df)

  Assumptions Index Proposition Premisses   Rule
0         [1]     1          ¬q         A     []
1         [2]     2         p→q         A     []
2         [3]     3           p         A     []
3       [2,3]     4           q        →E  [2,3]
4     [1,2,3]     5       q∧ ¬q        ∧I  [1,4]
5       [1,2]     6          ¬p        ¬I  [3,5]
```